# Convert mesh to stl/obj/fbx in runtime

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mesh, fbx

I am looking for a way to export a mesh into stl/obj/fbx format at runtime and save it on local files of an Android phone.

How do I do this? I am willing to use a plugin(free/paid) if it exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is really complicated since you have to read the specifications for each each format (stl/obj/fbx) and understand them in order to make one yourself. Luckily, there are many plugins out there already that can be used to export Unity mesh to stl, obj and fbx.

**FBX**:

[*UnityFBXExporter*](https://github.com/KellanHiggins/UnityFBXExporter) is used to export Unity mesh to fbx during run-time.

```
public GameObject objMeshToExport;

void Start()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "carmodel"+ ".fbx");

    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }

    FBXExporter.ExportGameObjToFBX(objMeshToExport, path, true, true);
}
```

---

**OBJ**:

For obj, [`ObjExporter`](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ObjExporter) is used.

```
public GameObject objMeshToExport;

void Start()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "carmodel" + ".obj");

    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }

    MeshFilter meshFilter = objMeshToExport.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    ObjExporter.MeshToFile(meshFilter, path);
}
```

---

**STL**:

You can use the [*pb_Stl*](https://github.com/karl-/pb_Stl) plugin for STL format.

```
public GameObject objMeshToExport;

void Start()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
    path = Path.Combine(path, "carmodel" + ".stl");

    Mesh mesh = objMeshToExport.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }


    pb_Stl.WriteFile(path, mesh, FileType.Ascii);

    //OR
    pb_Stl_Exporter.Export(path, new GameObject[] { objMeshToExport }, FileType.Ascii);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have never thought of finding plugin in Github...... I will try all these plugins later today.

Comment: I would like to develop an Android app(for a school project) that allows users to design their own phone cases and then generate 3D geometry files in STL/OBJ format, which is ready for 3D printing. (Sorry that I didnt make clear in the question.)

Thats the main reason I need a plugin for exporting gameobjects/meshes to stl/obj/fbx files at runtime in Android app.

I tried both pb_Stl and UnityFBXExporter in void Start() (codes you suggested). But when I turn on my app, and then I open the internal storage. I found that nothing was created.

Comment: I would like to know could these export codes being implemented in other functions instead of void Start(). Because what I want to achieve is generating a stl file only when a specific button is clicked instead of the start of the app.

Comment: All your comments are unnecessary. The code you see are just example usage and can be used or called anytime if you put them in an non `Start` function. You may need to call `Directory.Exists` and `Directory.CreateDirectory` before saving the model or you run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735735/android-unity-c-sharp-unauthorizedaccessexception-writing-save-game-data/) problem. Also made a typo by putting ".fbx" as extension of all of them. Now, fixed it. See the edit. You can check if the saving worked with `File.Exists`  or by reading the file with `File.ReadAllBytes`