# How to export a serialized mesh .asset file to fbx

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, export, mesh, fbx

In Unity3D I have a script-generated `Mesh` object. I've serialized it as an `.asset` file using `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset`, so now I have `/Asset/ExampleMesh.asset`.

However since external programs cannot open unity assets, I'm looking for a way to convert it to an fbx. In other words, I would like to be able to create `/Asset/ExampleMesh.fbx`.

---

In script, given a `Mesh` reference, is there any way to output an `.fbx` asset? I'm looking to write a helper function like this:

```
public static void ExportToFBXFile(Mesh mesh, string filepath)
{
    byte[] bytes = EncodeMeshToFBX(mesh);
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/" + filepath + ".fbx", bytes);
}
```

Where `EncodeMeshToFBX` would generate the byte representation of the mesh as an FBX.

I don't care about materials, animations, etc. I just want to go from a `Mesh` to a `.fbx` file.

*Note*: I've seen some plugin solutions that can take a gameobject and save it's hierarchy as an FBX. This is not what I'm looking for. I just want to export a Mesh type itself.

Comment: I'm arguing that this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733430 - that question is asking about gameobject to fbx saving, and the solutions provided all accept a gameobject. This is not what I am asking. I want to specifically serialize a `Mesh` without any gameobject involved.

Comment: It's doing extremely something similar. It takes GameObject as param, get's MeshFilter from it and converts it into an fbx format. You have two options: **1.** Create new GameObject, attach MeshFilter to it and the mesh then call the `FBXExporter.ExportGameObjToFBX` function and send that GameObject. You probably don't want to do #1 but it's simpler. **2.** Add a new function to the `FBXExporter` class. Copy the code from the `FBXExporter.ExportGameObjToFBX` function to it then change the function param to Mesh. Remove the GameObject code. Nothing complicated here.